# Как спрятать пароль от базы данных MySQL?

Tags: php, безопасность, mysql

Здравствуйте!
У меня три файла php в корне сайта. В одном из них идет подключение к базе данных:

```
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","mysql","1111");
```

Вот я  и думаю, как защитить этот файл от воровства пароля.
Я понимаю, что можно через htaccess к этому файлу доступ закрыть, но достаточно ли этого? Надежно ли это? Или пароль держать в спец. файле и спец закрытой папке в корне сайта?
Подскажите, как это грамотно делается? Я такого раньше не делал.

Спасибо всем!

Comment: И еще маленькое дополнение к вопросу:
Вот тут привели пример 2 способов
1)в корне сайта в папке хранить файл и закрыть доступ к ней
2)хранить в файл перед папкой cайта www

Вопрос: Какой метод надежней?

Comment: Надежней конечно 2.

Comment: Ну по фтп файл все равно сможешь редактировать, где бы он не лежал, главное чтоб доступ в эту папку был (на запись в том числе) для фтп пользователя. А phpmyadmin этот файл все равно не использует, так что для него это неважно.

Comment: а если вы сейчас обратитесь к этому скрипту, то он вам покажет логин и пароль?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все верно, в спец. папке должен лежать этот файлик, а не в корне сайта. А на папку соответствующие права.

Comment: DemoS спасибо! Как обычно выручаешь! А можешь дать ссылку на материал - какие права и как прописывать?
а подключение к файлу вот так делается? include_once('../db-site.php');

Comment: Сорри может я не в курсе, но как кто либо получит доступ к исполняющему пхп скрипту?))

Comment: Спасибо, DemoS!

Comment: Создал в корне сайта папку и там лежит файл подключения к базе, туда же скопировал файл `.htaccess(Order allow,deny
Deny from all)` с полным запретом доступа... думаю, этого достаточно)))

Comment: Ну да, так точно никто туда доступ иметь не будет. =)

Добавьте перед запретом:


Allow from localhost


Allow from 127.0.0.1

Comment: т.е в .htaccess нужно написать так:
Allow from localhost
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Order allow,deny Deny from all

т.е. зайти в эту папку смогу только я со своего компьютера подключивщись через ftp соединение.Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Должно быть так:

Order allow,deny

Allow from localhost

Allow from 127.0.0.1

Deny from all


Зайти можно в эту папку будет только с самого сервера и ниоткуда больше. Чтоб можно было еще и самому заходить удаленно, то надо еще дописать

Allow from <твой внешний IP>

Естественно IP желательно при этом иметь выделенный ну и обязательно статический.

Comment: > Allow from localhost
> Allow from 127.0.0.1

Что за сакральный смысл в этих строчках?

Comment: 2 @Ilya Pirogov, это не для файла с конфигом это для папки.

Comment: ... для папки в которой лежит конфиг. Зачем, если файл подключается через require_once?

Answer (score 2):

Из пхп то всё равно не вытащить, зачем прятать? Или поставь пароль на открытие пхп файла. А если взломают твою админ панель, то всё равно хоть в какой папке бы он не был, вытащить смогут.

Comment: а у меня и нет админ панели))) значит взломать будет сложнее)))

Comment: я имею ввиду eXplorer, ISPManager и т.п.

Answer (score 1):

Вынести конфиг с параметрами подключения к БД за пределы www (корневой директории хоста) и инклудить его уже оттуда.

Comment: например вот так?
require_once('\login.php');
т.е. сам файл лежит не в папке www, а перед ней...

Comment: Всего лишь подняться выше по иерархии ФС, например require_once('../login.php');

Comment: Чем этот способ надежнее способа:
1)в корне сайта в папке хранить файл и закрыть доступ к ней через .htaccess?

Comment: @qwerty17, тем, что этот способ проще, не требует никаких дополнительных файлов или настроек и будет работать с любым веб-сервером, а не только с apache.

Comment: проще это хорошо... а он более безопасен чем вышеизложенный?

Comment: Проще => меньше вероятности допустить ошибку => более безопасен.

Возьмем пример выше, где @DemoS предлагает добавить в .htaccess доступ из localhost. Если позже сисадмин решит поставить поверх апатча nginx для раздачи статики, то доступ к файлу будет вновь открыт.

Answer (score 1):

Еще дополнительный вариант защиты:
Настроить MySql так, что бы на него можно было зайти только с localhost. Поскольку PHP коннектится с сервера, ему будет достаточно. А из вне с логином и паролем зайти будет уже нельзя.

Comment: Как правило так и должно быть. Вот только в процессе разработки (как по мне) удобно подключаться к БД прям из IDE, и с нее же делать какие-либо запросы. На а если проект свой, то всегда есть что внем поменять, дополнить, поэтому процесс разработки редко заканчивается :)

Comment: @DemoS, вносить изменения в проекте вживую на продакшене - это моветон.

Comment: да почему же?! Есть допустим админка, для админки делаю новый модуль. Админка к паблик части в принципе никак не относится, так почему же и нет... Главное не забывать включать мозг :)

Comment: Потому что, хотя бы одно не атомарное изменение файлика, или не осторожное изменение конфига, или пропущенное условие в SQL запросе - и весь сайт лежит, к чертям. Хотя если посещаемость сайта 10 уников в сутки, тогда да, можно особо не парится :)

Comment: Я не спец в программировании, но нельзя разве код отладить у себя на Денвере, а потом уже просто заменить на хостинге? И ничего не лежит)))

Comment: @qwerty17, да, именно так и следует поступать.

Comment: @DemoS, а если у меня виртуальный сервер в аренде, то как мне ip адрес прописывать как ты вверху советуешь... если например я хочу редактировать сайт с ноута и моб интернета в любом месте, то тогда у меня не будет статического адреса... это так?

Comment: Да проще всего сделать CMOD на файл подключения к БД 644, и не порочить себе голову.

Comment: понятно) спасибо)